# How to preserve data generated in an AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am working on Android AsyncTask, I wish to make a progress bar during my program is loading. Here's how I make it.

```
A class is declared here...
private ArrayList<String> result1 = new ArrayList<String>(); //class variable

onCreate()
{
    Some stuff here...
    new ATask().execute();
     for (int i = 0; i <result1.size();i++)
    {
        output = output +result1.get(i) + "\n\n";
    }
    textView.setText(output);
}
private void do0()
{
    ArrayList<Sentence> result = new ArrayList<Sentence>();
    ArrayList<String> result2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    result = do1("link", true); //just some function I am working
    result1 = do2(result,10);//do2 return ArrayList<String>
}
private class ATask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private ProgressDialog progress = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        do0();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progress.dismiss();

        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(ReadWebPage.this);

        progress.setMessage("Doing...");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.show();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
};
```

My intention is that, while the progress bar is loading, it will finish the `do0()` and modify `result1`, then my `oncreate` can use that `result1` to display in it's `TextView`. However my `TextView` is always empty in this setting. So I move the

```
     for (int i = 0; i <result1.size();i++)
    {
        output = output +result1.get(i) + "\n\n";
    }
    textView.setText(output);
```

into the `do0()` (right after the `result1 = do2()`), but then the program will crash. I am not familiar with these thread settings, thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be better served with a thread that holds a `Handler` object that was initialized on the main thread. Using the handler, you can `post()` little snippets to be executed on a main thread - like update a progress bar. You can do the same Handler trick from the AsyncTask, but IMHO threads are cleaner.

Said snippets should be implemented as `Runnable`s. Feel free to use a nested anonymous class one-liner.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a better usage of the code, yet I get the one I use from the sample code. I am not very familiar with this right now, but I think your approach should be should when I got more mature coding ability. Thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the design of your code.  `AsyncTask` happens asynchronously, so as soon as you call execute on your `AsyncTask` the rest of your `onCreate` will execute immediately.  `AsyncTask` will essentially run on a new thread and execute in parallel with your `Activity`.

What I think you want is to set your `TextView` in the `onPostExecute` method of your `AsyncTask`.  `onPostExecute` gets called after `doInBackground` is finished.

Also, it is important to keep in mind that `doInBackground` happens on a background thread, so you cannot make changes to your `Activity's` UI from code within it.  `onPre/PostExecute` run on the UI thread, so you can make UI changes there, but any code within those methods will also block the UI.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Thanks for your clarification for the usage of `activities` and the `onPre/PostExecute` command. I get this from the sample code on the internet, so not very familiar with it. I extremely appreciate your help.